# VB.NET - Change LINQ query to DataSet query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, dataset

I have a VB.NET function to get list of complains based on status param. It is using LINQ method and is working ok:

```
Public Function getComplain(ByVal stat As Integer) As List(Of ComplainTable)
    Dim listt = (From tbl In context.ComplainTable _
                 Where tbl.STATUS = stat _
                 Select tbl).ToList
    Return listt
End Function
```

Question is I want to change the LINQ query to DataSet query instead. The code that I tried is as below, but I get empty result/output:

```
Public Function getComplain(ByVal stat As Integer) As List(Of ComplainTable)
    Dim ut As New Util

    Dim query = "SELECT * FROM ComplainTable"
    Dim ds As DataSet = ut.getData(query)
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("SystemComplain") '???
    Dim dr As IEnumerable(Of SystemComplain) = dt.AsEnumerable.Select("STATUS = " & stat) '???

    Return dr.ToList
End Function
```

The lines marked ??? are the parts that I'm not sure I'm doing correctly. I'm very newbie in .NET and need to search a lot on Internet just to get basic things done.

**UPDATE 1**

```
Public Function getComplain(ByVal stat As Integer) As List(Of ComplainTable)
    Dim ut As New Util

    Dim query = "SELECT * FROM ComplainTable"
    Dim ds As DataSet = ut.getData(query)
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Dim dr As IEnumerable(Of ComplainTable) = _
                     dt.AsEnumerable. _
                        Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("STATUS") = stat). _
                        Select(Function(x) New ComplainTable With { _
                            .STATUS = x.Field(Of String)("STATUS") _
                        } _
                        )

    Return dr.ToList
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference the DataTable initially by a name, since you didn't provide one.  You however CAN use the index.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
```

As for the filtering, instead of using .Select, try .Where on the second line in question.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code with question marks looks good to me, but if that doesn't work for you try to use index as suggested in the other answer. Anyway, for the next line, use [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method with proper predicate expression :

```
Dim dr As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = dt.AsEnumerable.
                                       Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of string)("STATUS") = stat)
```

For reference : [Queries in LINQ to DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**UPDATE :**

```
Dim dr As IEnumerable(Of ComplainTable) = _
                 dt.AsEnumerable.
                    Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of string)("STATUS") = stat).
                    Select(Function(x) New ComplainTable With {
                                                .STATUS = x.Field(Of string)("STATUS")
                                                'TODO: manually populate other properties here'
                                            }
                          )
                    }
```

Comment: I edited to use index for ds.Tables(0) and followed your IEnumerable line. But when I use IEnumerable(Of DataRow), I got error that DataRow cannot be converted to ComplainTable, which is the return type of the function.

Comment: @navilink You need to manually create `ComplainTable` instance from `DataRow` now. Initially, it is created by LINQ-to-SQL, now since you switch to LINQ-to-DataSet, you need to handle the same manually. Check **UPDATE** section

Comment: Ok I added your UPDATE code (removed last bracket due to syntax error), my latest code is in UPDATE 1 (in my original post). Still nothing is returned. I'm sure the Dataset has items because I managed to print out the content.